# MySQL doesn't start from Terminal, Mac OS El Capitan; none of solutions found work

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

I have read a few possible solutions on how to fix the problem with starting MySQL from the terminal. None has worked.

My system Mac OS El Capitan.

Whenever I try to start mysql from Terminal, I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

If I try to get connected via browser to phpmyadmin, I enter a correct user (root in my case) and a password, I get the following:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Here is very briefly information on the problem, and what I have checked.
Trying to solve the issue I did the following:

(1) have created `/etc` folder in `/usr/local/mysql`

(2) copied `my-default.cnf` in `/usr/local/mysql/support-files`, 
the copy is named `my.cnf`; moved `my.cnf` to

```
/usr/local/mysql/etc
directory
```

but didn't change the file anyhow, didn't add anything to it manually; so it still have default configurations;

(3) ran in terminal:

```
netstat -na |grep 3306

tcp46      0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

(4) than ran:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

got this:

```
    mynamehere            2575   1.3  0.0  2444056    824 s000  S+   12:29PM   0:00.01 grep mysql
_mysql           989   0.0  0.2  2893920   8896   ??  Ss   10:21AM   0:04.62 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
```

From this I see that I have a correct `user=_mysql`

(5) tried again to run mysql from the terminal using `mysql -v -u root –p`, got the same error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

(6) I still **can** get it running **only via System Preferences**.

(7) As the above revealed I have a correct user, so I didn’t run       `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`            ;
but I did run   `sudo chown -R _mysql data/`   just for the sake of it, though it didn’t change anything.

(8) went to: `cd /Library/LaunchDaemons`
to see `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

```
sudo launchctl load -F com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

revealed that everything is running ok (this was when I have manually started mysql via system preferences):

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist: service already loaded
```

(9) tried to see the contents of `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` by

```
sudo nano com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

and this showed something bizarre (not the html content I have seen everywhere):

```
bplist00�^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H
^K^L
^N^O^P^Q^Q^Q^T^P^U^V^Q^W^_[ExitTimeOut_^P^PWorkingDirectoryYGroupNameXDisabledY$
```

I will be truly grateful for your help!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, someone help me with this issue. Although I can run my C program once I physically turn on mysql from system preferences, I can't do so by trying to connect via Terminal, or via my C program, which essentially connects as if via Terminal. It seems I miss something. When I connect via `system preferences`, I am required to enter my computer's password (not mysql one), and then mysql starts. I don't do that via Terminal though; I only enter `mysql -v -u root -p`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Mac OSX Sierra.
I ended up restoring my com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist from TimeMachine which restored it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 

"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>             <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>       <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>     <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>          <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>         <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>       <integer>600</integer>
    <key>Program</key>           <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--user=_mysql</string>
            <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
            <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
            <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
            <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
             <string>--keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring</string>
             <string>--early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so</string>

        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>  <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` set `RunAtLoad` and `KeepAlive` to `<true />`.